# variables substitution (or overriding) when extends jobs from gitlab templates unsing include

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

Using gitlab ci, I have a repo where all my templates are created. 
For example, I have a sonar scanner job template named `.sonar-scanner.yml`:

```
sonar-analysis:
  stage: quality
  image:
    name: sonar-scanner-ci:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - sonar-scanner
      -D"sonar.projectKey=${SONAR_PROJECT_NAME}"
      -D"sonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN}"
      -D"sonar.host.url=${SONAR_SERVER}"
      -D"sonar.projectVersion=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
      -D"sonar.projectBaseDir=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
```

I have include this template as a project like this in main gitlab ci file:

```
include: 
  - project: 'organization/group/ci-template'
    ref: master
    file: '.sonar-scanner.yml'
```

So as you can understand I have a repo named ci-templates where all my templates are created. And in another repo, I extends using **include** these templates.

Finally, in a repo, when a new merge request is created, my job for sonar is running under another file in my project `test/quality.yml`:

```
sonar:
  stage: quality
  extends: 
    - sonar-analysis 
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
```

All is working well except the substitution or the overriding of my env var. Indeed  of my template. I have many sonar server or project names. I would like to know how to override these variables `SONAR_SERVER` and `SONAR_PROJECT_NAME` when I extend the job from a template.

In my main `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have a variables section declaration, and when I override these variables in, it works.
But it's not really what I want. Using many stages and many micro service it is possible to reuse the same extending job in a different way. That I really want to do is to override these variables directly in the file `test/quality.yml`.

This, for example does not work:

```
sonar:
  stage: quality
  extends: 
    - sonar-analysis
  variables:
    SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: foo
    SONAR_SERVER: bar
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
```

This not work too:

```
variables:
  SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: foo
  SONAR_SERVER: bar

sonar:
  stage: quality
  extends: 
    - sonar-analysis 
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
```

What is the best way to make this work ?

Comment: I would have thought the first example would have worked... what happens if you try adding a `before_script` to just echo out the variables?

If you have a top level `.gitlab-ci.yml` and then include the `test/quality.yml`, the top level `.gitlab-ci.yml` variables will override that of the `quality.yml` I believe...

Comment: @Rekovni inded, if I put the var in the main `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the var will be overrided and it works well, but it's not that I need, I really need to find a way to make this in the `test.quality.yml`. If I use a `.before_script` nothing works.

Comment: Does `before_script: - echo $SONAR_PROJECT_NAME etc` not work in the `sonar` stage?
Can you show how you have done the top level `.gitlab-ci` so far?

Comment: That's weird because gitlab uses variables in their templates https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this question was asked in Feburary 2020, a new MR [Use non-predefined variables inside CI include blocks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/66852) has been merged into Gitlab 14.2, which resolves the issue for the overridden job.

The project that does the include can redefine the variables when extending a job:

```yaml
include: 
  - project: 'organization/group/ci-template'
    ref: master
    file: '.sonar-scanner.yml'

sonar:
  stage: quality
  extends: 
    - sonar-analysis
  variables:
    SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: foo
    SONAR_SERVER: bar
  allow_failure: true
```

But in this case you probably want the job in the template to start with a dot `.sonar-analysis` instead of `sonar-analysis` to not create a real `sonar-analysis` job in the template (see [hidden jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#hide-jobs)).

Or you can also directly set the variables values (to redefine them) of an existing job in the project that does the include:

```yaml
include: 
  - project: 'organization/group/ci-template'
    ref: master
    file: '.sonar-scanner.yml'

sonar-analysis:
  variables:
    SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: foo
    SONAR_SERVER: bar
```

I verified this with [a test project](https://gitlab.com/milohax-test/gl/includes-overrides/test), which includes a template from [a peer test project](https://gitlab.com/milohax-test/gl/includes-overrides/templates/-/blob/main/.sonar-scanner.yml), and when it runs, results in two jobs. This is the [job output for the overriding job](https://gitlab.com/milohax-test/gl/includes-overrides/test/-/jobs/2730641583):

```
$ echo sonar.projectKey=${SONAR_PROJECT_NAME}
sonar.projectKey=foo
$ echo sonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN}
sonar.login=bob
$ echo sonar.host.url=${SONAR_SERVER}
sonar.host.url=bar
```

Comment: Or better yet use `inputs:` https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/05/08/use-inputs-in-includable-files/